Deno wont output
I have a file index.js Im using Deno for my project. When I run my file deno run index.js I get no terminal output and the port wont open.
function app(){
    return `
      <div class="header">
        <h1>Deno Project</h1>
      </div>
    `;
  }
  
  Deno.serve({ port: 8000 }, async (_req) => {
    return new Response(
        [
          app()
        ].join(''),
        {
            status: 200,
            headers: { "content-type": "text/html" },
        }
    );
  });

I factory reset my computer about a week ago and reinstalled Deno since but I cant find why this is not running. Any help would be nice.

What do you mean by "no terminal output"? Could you try running it again with --allow-net flag?

@Kotkoroid Its been weeks, I even factory reset my computer and redownloaded it all. I get no terminal output on any file with any flag. I cant open or write content to anything, like a port.
